# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

while trying to insert genename in ms access table through java code  I am getting the error as

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression 'Saccharomyces cerevisiae (strain ATCC 204508 / S288c)'.
>     at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)    at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3117)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
>     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:287)
>     at sequence.SequenceAnalyser.(SequenceAnalyser.java:50)

my code is

```
try{
    executeUpdate = odbc.state.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO genename (GENE )VALUES ("+result+")");
    odbc.state.close();
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: Put the results of your query into a local variable and set a breakpoint there to see whether you're getting valid SQL. But in any case, you should be doing parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `result` string contains

```
Saccharomyces cerevisiae (strain ATCC 204508 / S288c)
```

so when you *inject* that raw string into your *SQL* statement you end up with invalid syntax.

Instead, you should be using a *parameterized query* like this

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO genename (GENE) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, result);
ps.executeUpdate();
```